# Ruby on Rails with Mongo DataBase

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, mongoid

I am a neophyte in this topics.
I have been trying to install and run MongoDB on my Windows OS.I installed MongoId

```
rails g mongoid:config
```

The above command is not creating config File. 
I created the file manually.I skipped the ActionController gem During Creation of App.To use mongoId Config file in rails app.

But,I am not sure how to start server in mongoDB.
And insert Into it in Rails application.In most of the Blog Post they jumped out of this step.

The Documentation in MongoDB is not clear.Please,Help me in correct installation and starting,inserting and retrieving data from MongoDB in rails application on Windows OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you should install MongoDB on Windows(refer to [this link](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/))

then add `mongoid` to Gemfile.

```
gem 'mongoid', '~> 5.0.0.beta'
```

run `bundle install`.

then run `rails g mongoid:config` to generate `mongoid.yml`

then start rails server by command `rails server` or `rails s`

> Mongoid supports all expected CRUD operations for those familiar with other Ruby mappers like Active Record or Data Mapper

if you want to insert a document into the mongodb, you can do like this:

```
Person.create(
  first_name: "Heinrich",
  last_name: "Heine"
)
```

get document from mongodb:

```
Person.where(first_name: "Heinrich")
```

You can get more info from [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial/#standard)

Comment: Can you please say how to insert data into a mongodb server from command or a rails app.Everthing above worked fine.Thank you

Comment: Thank you.Started learning CRUD and created my first collection.Then,how to retrieve data into my rails controller from mongoDB collections.

Comment: For example: `Person.where(first_name: "Heinrich")`

Comment: How to configure our rails server to take data from mongoDB.

Comment: @ashr81 you should modify the  `mongoid.yml`, you can get more detail info from [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial/#anatomy-of-a-mongoid-config)

Comment: How to check my rails server is running on mongoDB?

Comment: @ashr81if your rails app is not connected to mongodb, you cannot insert or query data normally. This is the sample way.

Comment: can you please send me a sample mongoDB or mongoid.yml file or a link to a sample project!

Comment: @ashr81 This is my [project(rails + mongodb)](https://github.com/liuzxc/mongo_project), hope it can help you.

Comment: Its more easy than expected.Thank you for the help.